# image coming afterwards

Tags: html, canvas

I am making a page and using canvas.. So in the body part i am doing something like this:

```
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300" height="1150">

</canvas>

<img src="arbit.png" width ="1000" height="1000" />

</body>
```

But the image is loading after the canvas space and the drawing on canvas is appearing above the image.

Can anybody tell me whats the problem?

**EDIT:**

Sorry mistake framing the question..

I want to overlap canvas and image ....

Comment: Please choose yours tags better in the future.. this is HTML5/Canvas question and got nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

You need to use some CSS positioning to get the two elements to overlap.

Check out [this JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ejiku3/2) I just knocked up to see it in action

**Markup:**

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt="test" width ="50" height="50" />

</div>
</body>
```

**Css:**

```
  .wrapper {
    position:relative;
  }

  .wrapper canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
  }

  .wrapper img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:20px;
    z-index;2;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<img>` element **is** after the `<canvas>` element, that's why the image is being displayed after (below) canvas.

Comment: With CSS, you would need to wrap both elements, then position the img over the canvas. Not sure how well this will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<body>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300" height="1150">
      <img src="arbit.png" width ="1000" height="1000" />
   </canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems you can't put an img inside a canvas. Or I couldn't get it to work at least.

Comment: Would need to see the accompanying javascript to see if it's being rendered correctly into the canvas.